# Retrieve Google Maps API key from appliacation.properties of a Spring Boot Project?

Tags: html, spring-boot, google-maps, spring-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API key in my project using

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places,geometry&callback=checkMaps">
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the API Key from application.properties of my Spring Boot Project.

Comment: Where are you writing <script> / HTML, is this MVC ? or anything else

Comment: No, it is a separate HTML file.

Comment: What is the location of that file? Can you please update your question with project structure